# Azure Synapse trigger when upload data into a table

Tags: sql, azure, triggers, azure-synapse, eventtrigger

I want to track what files are written to a Synapse table in real-time, which means when a pipeline writes data to a Synapse table I want to create meta data about that write operation and write it in another table.
I have tried using SQL trigger keyword, but it seems Synapse doesnt support TRIGGER as SQL server does.
Azure ADF or Synapse trigger does not have data upload trigger, only scheduled and storage event on file upload or delete.
If someone have a different logic, approach, azure service in mind, it will be amazing.
Thanks in advance

Comment: if we store the metadata in a separate table or as a file in blob storage, will that be fine for you?

Comment: Hi Utkarsh Pal,
Is there a way to modify the meta-data I want to store?
For example, I want to track the files name that have been uploaded to a table in Synapse, the table name which they have been uploaded, time stamp, size of the file etc.
Is that data is reachble in the sokution you suggeted below?

Answer (score 0):

Auditing for Azure Synapse Analytics tracks database events and writes them to an audit log in your Azure storage account, Log Analytics workspace, or Event Hubs.

In your Dedicated SQL Pool. Go to the `Security -> Auditing` option on the left panel and **Enable Azure SQL Auditing**.

**Select the storage account** where you want to store all the logs for your SQL Database activities. Click on **Save**.

[image]

Once enabled, you can see a new container will be created in your storage account with default name `sqldbauditlogs`.

[image]

Inside the container you can find all audit files as show in below image.

[image]

These files can be downloaded and use SQL Server Management Studio (SSMS) to read the event details.

[image]