Azure Synapse/ Datawarehouse DML monitoring of tables
Does azure synapse have any concept triggers to monitor insert, update, delete, if no
then what is the Alternate?
We are moving from oracle adw to azure synapse, would like to know any way to monitor deletions for tables.

No, the DB doesn;t support trigger, you'll have to use SQL Auditing this is
good place to start https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73486233/azure-synapse-trigger-when-upload-data-into-a-table

I agree with @jon
Enabling auditing for Azure Synapse Analytics allows you to track database events and store them in an audit log.
To enable auditing for your Dedicated SQL Pool, you need to go to the Security section and select the Auditing option on the left panel.
Then, you can enable Azure SQL Auditing and choose the storage account where you want to store all the logs for your SQL Database activities.
Finally, click on Save to apply the changes.

After you enable auditing for Azure Synapse Analytics and select the storage account to store the logs, a new container will be automatically created in your storage account.
This container will have a default name of "SqlDbAuditing_Audit_NoRetention".

Inside the container you can find all the audit files as shown below:

